# MVC 1 RenderAction

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, html-helper

I'm working in a MVC 1 project, I've used in a couple of places Html.RenderAction and for that I've referenced the Microsoft.Web.Mvc library. It works fine in local, but the moment that I upload it to the server it fails (althoug the library is in the correct place and it's properly referenced as far as I know).

It gives me this compilation error

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'RenderAction' and no extension method 'RenderAction' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I understood it came with the library I reference, not with System.Web.Mvc (which is as well referenced nontheless), but actually when I hover over Html.RenderAction in my views it seems to be using System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelpers although I can't explicitely write this route

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it's live and working fine. This is just to add some functionality

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there ISNT a RenderAction by default back in mvc 1, you have to get the external assebly for it, the below quote backs me up on this

> RenderAction() is defined in the MVC Futures assembly.  You can
>   download it from
>   http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471.
>   Be sure to import the Microsoft.Web.Mvc namespace in your project's
>   ~\Web.config.

Taken from: [This Site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1445247.aspx/1)

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and it works fine in local but not in the server

Comment: oh ofc, how did i overlook that, my mistake ill keep searching

Comment: @mitomed my best guess would be that when it is run locally it works because the dll is there on the macheine to be referenced, when you upload it to the server it complains about it not existing, to me this suggests the referenced dll is not being uploaded to the server when it should be,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I eventually did.

First of all, appart of thank RhysW for your responses, I realize now that I should have clearly stated, although I mentioned it, that I used Html.RenderAction, so it was actually using System.Web.Mvc and I didn't know till the problem arouse. I don't know why it worked in my local, but it did.

For making it work in the remote machine, I've changed the code to Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewExtensions.RenderAction beeing Microsoft.Web.Mvc redundant and no needed.

Thanks